# plocate -d not searching multiple databases

Tags: locate, 21.04

Ubuntu 21.04. I want to search multiple databases (created for external drives) using plocate:

```
plocate -d ~/.db1.db:~/.db2.db: -i -r "SEARCH_TERM"
```

Whenever I run that using queries that I know have matching results within db2, I get results that instead end with (after the listing of matches from db1):

```
~/.db2.db: No such file or directory
```

That is reported even if I swap the order of the two dbs around, i.e. 2 & 1 instead of 1 & 2. In that case it reports:

```
~/.db1.db: No such file or directory
```

even though I'd run it just before prior to the swap and found matches in db1.

That is *even* the case if I specify the same db twice, i.e. db1 & db1 or db2 & db2. First it lists the matches from dbX, then at the end it reports no such file or directory for dbX.

Man pages for plocate such as here: https://plocate.sesse.net/plocate.1.html
indicate that the colon character can be used to separate different databases previously created using updatedb. I also found suggestions on the web that the trailing colon with nothing after it ensured that the default db would also be included/searched.

If I give only the one custom db:

```
plocate -d ~/.db1.db: -i -r "SEARCH_TERM"
```

then I get a similar result (after the matches from db1):

```
No such file or directory
```

which I presume relates to the default db?

The behaviour observed seems to suggest that only the first db is actually being searched, and that any *second* db listed produces an error, even if there is also a third db listed. I checked that by putting the default db in the middle:

```
plocate -d ~/.db1.db::~/.db2.db -i -r "SEARCH_TERM"
```

and again I got the error message seemingly corresponding to the default db:

```
No such file or directory
```

and matches only found from db1 but not db2.

Comment: The shell will replace the leading `~` with your home directory, but the later one will be passed to `plocate` literally - I wonder if that's a factor here?

Comment: Excellent suggestion. The following worked: 
```MY_PATH=$HOME *newline goes here*
plocate -d "$MY_PATH/.db1.db":"$MY_PATH/.db2.db": -i -r "SEARCH_TERM"```

Comment: @JayBee you could just use `$HOME` directly instead of the `MY_PATH` stuff.

Comment: @JayBee are you still having issues with the default database? if not, I will convert the comment into an answer

Comment: I think my query is answered, thank you. I still get error reports relating to the default database, and don't get any results of searches from there--e.g. if I perform a query for something I know it should find in my home directory. I've checked and there is a file at: `/var/lib/plocate` of a size (8.7mb) suggesting it contains an index of files. But such is really an add-on to my original question/problem relating to the custom databases for removable drives, so if you wish to close this as solved then fine.

Comment: correction: the file is at '/var/lib/plocate/plocate.db'

Comment: If someone could move the comment to an answer, we could close the question and have an answered question for future visitors.

Comment: The following produce the results one would expect `plocate -d '/var/lib/plocate/plocate.db' -i -r "Music"`, also `plocate "Music"`, etc. So I think the earlier failure (after solving the second ~ being read literally, that is) was simply the combination of explicitly targeting custom databases and an implicit reference to the default one in the same statement. It seems more like an either/or but not both. If one explicitly targets both a custom and the default db it also works as expected: `plocate -d "$HOME/.db1.db":'/var/lib/plocate/plocate.db' -i -r "Music"`